# fs.rename elimina archivos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, filesystem

quiero tomar el valor de cada archivo json y con eso cambiar su nombre. pero al ejecutar solo a algunos se les cambia el nombre y el resto desaparece.
Probé reemplazar el fs.rename por fs.renameSync pero tampoco me ha dado resultados, ocurre lo mismo

```
let min = 6349
let max = 6400

const getData = () => {
  for (let i = min; i < max; i++) {
    let filePath = `./data/json/${i}.json`;
    const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    let obj = JSON.parse(data);
    rename(i, obj);
  }
};

const rename = (i, obj) => {
  fs.rename(
    `./data/json/${i}.json`,
    `./data/json/${obj.edition}.json`,
    (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );

  fs.rename(
    `./data/images/${i}.png`,
    `./data/images/${obj.edition}.png`,
    (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
};

getData();
```

Comment: ¿Será que por algún motivo estás poniéndole el mismo nombre a más de un archivo? En la [documentación](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrenameoldpath-newpath-callback) dice que si ya existe un archivo con dicho nombre, este será reemplazado.

Comment: @Mateo Gracias por responder! No es eso, los archivos que preciso modificar tienen nombres unicos y lo he verificado varias veces ya :/